# Timeout issue for long requests on ajax POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, azure, timeout

so I have a .NET MVC project with an Update controller called from an Ajax POST that can take a long time to run which causes a timeout exception.

When I debug it on my local machine it runs fine, however - when I publish it to my azure website and update it from there the request never successfully completes and Chrome's console reports:

```
POST http://mysiteaddress/Admin/UpdateLibrary/Update?Length=13 504 (Proxy Timeout ( This operation returned because the timeout period expired. ))
```

Attempting the same operation on a remote desktop within Firefox causes the console to report:

```
[07:42:13.856] POST http://mysiteaddress/Admin/UpdateLibrary/Update?Length=13 **[HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway 182940ms]**
```

I've tried setting a long timeout within my web.config file

```
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="2000"/>
```

and within the body of my ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            document.write(data);
        },
        failure: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        timeout: 2000000 //Milliseconds
    });
```

But no joy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is not really a fix, but a workaround. Instead of making a single long request I had my javascript repeatedly query an ActionResult that returned some json deciding whether my long running process had finished. When it had completed I redirect the browser to a results screen.

```
    $.updateProgressbar = function () {
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetStatus", "UpdateLibrary", new { countryId = countryId }, Request.Url.Scheme)', function (data) {
            $('#progressbar').progressbar('value', data.progress)
            if (data.currentItem != null) {
                $('#currentWorkItem').text('@l12.View_Update_currentlyWorking' + data.currentItem);
        }
            if (data.progress == 100) {
                window.location =
                    '@Url.Action("UpdateResults", "UpdateLibrary", new { countryId = countryId }, Request.Url.Scheme)';
            } else {
                setTimeout($.updateProgressbar, 5000);
            }
        });
    };

    $(function () {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
        setTimeout($.updateProgressbar, 5000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like on your local network to external azure site, you are going out through a proxy/gateway server. Does your company have any block-lists or white-lists for allowed/disallowed websites that might be intercepting and blocking the request?

Comment: You're right, I do connect through a proxy. There don't seem to be any blacklists on our server. I did go into our Server settings and change the default connection timeouts for Web requests to be longer. This converted it to the same error I received on my remote desktop - `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)`